# robots.txt in version control

Tags: version-control, robots.txt

My web development team has a version control system setup with two branches. One of these branches are for development, the other has the stable code which is displayed on our primary domain. For ease of testing during development, we have a second domain from which the development branch is served.

I want to maintain our robots.txt file in the version control system, but I don't want our development website showing up in search results. If I put a robots.txt file in the development branch that disallows all indexing, the development domain will serve that file solving one of my problems. But, as soon as I merge that change with the stable branch, that same file will get served from the primary domain, which isn't what I want. What would you do in this situation to resolve both issues?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to use a domain name which does not resolve in the public DNS. Then set up your own internal DNS server, or add the host to your local `/etc/hosts` or equivalent.

Comment: @tripleee That would only work if we only had one developer or all of our developers were in the same location (on the same network).

Comment: Huh? No, you just need to make sure everyone have the required settings. Perhaps set up a VPN to simplify routing.

Comment: @tripleee I appreciate your suggestion, but I'm not about to setup a VPN so that I don't need to serve a robots.txt file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach, if you're using Apache:

1. Create two robots.txt files instead of one: `robots-production.txt`, and `robots-development.txt`
2. Add two .htaccess rules:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your_development_domain$
   RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots-development.txt

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your_production_domain$
   RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots-production.txt
   ```

This serves a different robots.txt file for each domain.

Comment: This seems like a viable solution, but I haven't been able to get it to work. This is what I have in my configuration:  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots-development.txt`
This comes right after the www redirection rules which are working fine, so I know that the rewrite engine is working.

Comment: That's weird, I just tested it on two different servers and it worked fine. Can you pastebin your entire .htaccess file please?

Comment: I am doing this in an apache conf file rather than a .htaccess file. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MqM12Vkh)

Comment: Do you see any conflicting rules in my configuration?

Comment: No, I see absolutely nothing wrong :| If you remove the RewriteCond, do all the robots.txt requests map to robots-development.txt?

Comment: No, `RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots-development.txt` without the RewriteCond still results in `File does not exist: /var/www/<subdirectory>/robots.txt`

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. RewriteRules are relative to the <Directory> directive they are defined in (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Can you wrap the rules in a <Directory /var/www/<subdirectory>></Directory> section?

Comment: Putting the rules in a <Directory> as you suggested worked, even with the RewriteCond rule.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped.